# Ubuntu 20.04 issues with TP Link AC1300 Archer T4U ( rtl8812au )

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, network-manager, tp-link

I can't force my USB wireless card (TP-Link AC1300 Archer T4U with rtl8812au) to work with Ubuntu. rtl8812au-dkms package from Ubuntu repo doesn't help (module is not even loaded when I connect USB device).

I've also tried drivers from GitHub (gordboy, aircrack). I see that device is loading those modules when connected, but... I can't force network card to came up, or scan networks.

With them I only see that wireless card appeared in "ip a" list, "iw info" (I see that it support both [2.4Ghz and 5Ghz] bands), and Ubuntu (GUI) NetworkManager. But I can't force it to become UP or scan networks.

Console output (last MAC chars changed):

```
lsusb
(...)
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 2357:0115 TP-Link 802.11ac NIC
```

```
ip a
(...)
   7: wlx00e04cxxxxxx: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 2312 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
   link/ether 00:e0:4c:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

```
$ ip link set wlx00e04cxxxxxx up
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

```
$ iwlist wlx00e04cxxxxxx scan
wlx00e04cxxxxxx No scan results
```

```
$ wpa_supplicant -B -i wlx00e04cxxxxxx -c wpa.conf -D nl80211
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Could not set interface wlx00e04cxxxxxx flags (UP): Operation not permitted
nl80211: Could not set interface 'wlx00e04cxxxxxx' UP
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlx00e04cxxxxxx disabled_11b_rates=0
wlx00e04cxxxxxx: Failed to initialize driver interface
```

MAC address is successfully reared from device. Also information about two bands. I think that module is successfully loaded and recognize device, but somehow can't control (send instructions) it.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: 'rfkill list all` and also: `dmesg | grep -e wlx -e 8812` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Right now I experiment with other driver versions/forks from GitHub, so I'm not able to check it on drivers mentioned in question. The tricky thing is, that when I use: https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu (version for rtl8822bu, not 8812au) card is working, but only with 2.4Ghz...

Comment: When using github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu also MAC address seams to be different ( wlxd03745xxxxxx, not wlx00e04cxxxxxx as before).

Comment: I've got another update. Still using github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu driver I can see some of 5G networks and be able to connect/use them, but not all 5G networks. I think it depends on each network channel, and will try to confirm it. 

Anyway it seams that my TP-Link AC1300 Archer T4U has rtl8822bu instead of rtl8812au. If anyone with the same problem can confirm it - i'll be grateful.